# Point positions of a rotating rectangle

Tags: c#, math, rotation, points, rectangles

I have a rectangle which i want to rotate.

I have just one point of the rectangle (mouse Position), the lenght and the width of the rectangle and the angle of the rotation. Now i need the position of the other three corners of the rectangle so that i can easily draw my rectangle with *Graphics.DrawPolygon()*.

I have no idea, as i hadn't math for some years and need your help :D

I have tried many solutions from the internet but nothing really fit for my problem.

Comment: what is relation between *rotation* and *rectangle drawn* ? And rotation arround what *center point* ?

Comment: there is 1 rectangle, and 1 textbox or similar where the user has to write the angle of the rotation.. and the rectangle redraws with the new positions.. center point is the mouse position (the center of the rectangle or the upper left of the rectangle (couldn't decide yet)).. and for that i need the positions of the corners.. so 3 or 4 x and y

Comment: So you create *always* traignle aligned to some specifi axis/surface, say to X axis. One time its drawn, apply required rotation arroun specified point.

Comment: yes i always create a rectangle, but at the moment without an angle

Answer (score 3):

The following class does what you are looking for. For reference, take a look at how rotation works: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

```
public class MyRectangle
{
    public double Length { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Rotation { get; private set; }
    public Coord Center { get; private set; }
    public Coord TopLeft { get; private set; }
    public Coord TopRight { get; private set; }
    public Coord BottomLeft { get; private set; }
    public Coord BottomRight { get; private set; }

    public MyRectangle(Coord origin, double length, double width)
    {
        Length = length;
        Width = width;
        Center = origin;

        BottomLeft = new Coord(Center.X - Width / 2, Center.Y - Length / 2);
        BottomRight = new Coord(Center.X + Width / 2, Center.Y - Length / 2);
        TopLeft = new Coord(Center.X - Width / 2, Center.Y + Length / 2);
        TopRight = new Coord(Center.X + Width / 2, Center.Y + Length / 2);
    }

    private void Move(Coord c)
    {

        InitCorners(new Coord((c.X - Center.X), (c.Y - Center.Y)));
        Center.X = Center.X + (c.X - Center.X);
        Center.Y = Center.Y + (c.Y - Center.Y);
    }

    private void InitCorners(Coord c)
    {
        BottomRight.X = (BottomRight.X + c.X );
        BottomRight.Y = (BottomRight.Y + c.Y);

        BottomLeft.X = (BottomLeft.X + c.X);
        BottomLeft.Y = (BottomLeft.Y + c.Y);

        TopRight.X = (TopRight.X + c.X);
        TopRight.Y = (TopRight.Y + c.Y);

        TopLeft.X = (TopLeft.X + c.X);
        TopLeft.Y = (TopLeft.Y + c.Y);
    }

    public void Rotate(double qtyRadians)
    {
        //Move center to origin
        Coord temp_orig = new Coord(Center.X, Center.Y);
        Move(new Coord(0, 0));

        BottomRight = RotatePoint(BottomRight, qtyRadians);
        TopRight = RotatePoint(TopRight, qtyRadians);
        BottomLeft = RotatePoint(BottomLeft, qtyRadians);
        TopLeft = RotatePoint(TopLeft, qtyRadians);

        //Move center back
        Move(temp_orig);
    }

    Coord RotatePoint(Coord p, double qtyRadians)
    {
        Coord temb_br = new Coord(p.X, p.Y);
        p.X = temb_br.X * Math.Cos(qtyRadians) - temb_br.Y * Math.Sin(qtyRadians);
        p.Y = temb_br.Y * Math.Cos(qtyRadians) + temb_br.X * Math.Sin(qtyRadians);

        return p;
    }
}

[DebuggerDisplay("({X},{Y})")]
public class Coord
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public Coord(double x, double y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}
```